# How can I send Firebase User Email to MongoDB using React Hook Forms?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-hook-form

Want to send my user email that I have from Firebase Login to my MongoDB Database. I'm using **react hook form** to **Add New Product** (product name, information, price, quantity etc.) and also send my User Email with this form data.
I've solved this kinds of problems using **Axios.Post** method. Now I want to do this using **React Hook Form** . I need help solving this problem...
Screenshot: [This is my form data handler, and I've imported useAuthState(auth) to get user email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOWqT.png)

Comment: Please add code as code blocks in text format not screenshots

Answer (score 0):

```
onSubmit= data => {
   data.email = user?.email;
}
```

Add this line in onSubmit and the rest of the code will be the same.